# SQL: select purchases of customers for period, select result sum of all these purchases

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 simple tables: products(id, title, price), customers(id, name, last_name), purchases(id, customer_id, product_id, purchase_date).
I am trying to get customers statistic of purchases for period and as well total costs of all customers for this period.

I tried this query:

```
`String query =  "SELECT SUM(price) last_name, name, title, price FROM customers 
             JOIN purchases ON customers.id=purchases.customer_id 
             JOIN products ON products.id=purchases.product_id 
             WHERE purchase_date BETWEEN ? AND ? 
             GROUP BY customers.id";`
```

But this doesn't work.
What I excpect to get:

```
`"name": "John Roberts", 
 "purchases": [ // list all unique purchases
 {"title": "apples", 
 "expenses": 45 // Sum all purchases of this product for period
 },
 {"title": "cheese", 
 "expenses": 255
 },                    
 ...
 ],
 "totalExpenses": 300 //Of this customer

 "name": "Jack Smith", //next customer
 "purchases": [ // list all unique purchases]
 ,
 "totalExpenses": 4508, //All customers for this period
 "avgExpenses": 455 `
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when you use aggregate , non-aggregate fields should be in `group by` statement

```
SELECT
c.name AS customer_name,
p.title AS product_title,
SUM(p.price) AS expenses,
cust_total.totalExpenses
FROM customers AS c
INNER JOIN purchases AS pu ON c.id = pu.customer_id
INNER JOIN products AS p ON p.id = pu.product_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        c.id AS customer_id,
        SUM(pr.price) AS totalExpenses
    FROM customers AS c
    INNER JOIN purchases AS pu ON c.id = pu.customer_id
    INNER JOIN products AS pr ON pr.id = pu.product_id
    WHERE pu.purchase_date BETWEEN ? AND ?
    GROUP BY c.id
) AS cust_total ON c.id = cust_total.customer_id
WHERE pu.purchase_date BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY c.name, p.title, cust_total.totalExpenses;
```